# Proving two sets are equal if the size of the intersection and union are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove the following:
if $|X \cap Y| = |X \cup Y|$, then $X=Y$. But not sure how to do this mathematically. I am using this prove the property of indiscernibles. But not sure where to start with this when the size of the intersection/union is thrown into the mix. Would it be the same as proving $X \cap Y = X \cup Y$ or are there edge cases I'm missing?

Would the right step be to prove the inverse using DeMorgan's law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$X \cup Y = (X \cap Y) \sqcup (X \setminus Y) \sqcup (Y \setminus X),$$
where $\sqcup$ indicates disjoint union.
So
$$|X \cup Y| = |X \cap Y| + |X \setminus Y| + |Y \setminus X|.$$
Now what can you conclude about the last two terms?

Comment: |X \ Y| and |Y \ X| must be equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, so $X \setminus Y = Y \setminus X = \emptyset$, which implies that $X=Y$.

Comment: Was there some assumption of finiteness that we weren't aware of? $X=[0,2]$ and $Y=[1,3]$ are definitely not the same (unless, of course, $0=1$ and $2=3$) and $|X\cap Y|=|X\cup Y|$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I assumed finiteness from the discrete-mathematics tag and because otherwise it is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X\cap Y\subset X\subset X\cup Y$ so if these two sets have the same size, and $X,Y$ are *finite*, then you must have equality instead of inclusion. Likewise for $Y$.
If they are infinite, by the way, you could have $|X\cap Y|=|X\cup Y|$ while $X\neq Y$, for example choosing $X=Z$ and $Y=N$ would do the trick. However, if $X\cap Y=X\cup Y$, this always works.